# Android: how to search a word or a phrase with Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

My problem is: how can I search a word or a phrase in the page selected with Jsoup.
For example if the word or phrase in in a span how can I find per example the text next to this `<span>`? For example a link?

Html example code:

```
   ...
  <div class="div">
  <span>my y favourite text </span>
  <a href="www.mylink.com">my link </a>
  </div>
   ....
```

From this example how to find that my word is favourite and I also want to retrieve the link in `<a href>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8451801/7012517  refer to this link..!

Comment: Thank you...I read that but i have not understand what he does :(

Comment: @shobhit have you have other alternatives?

Comment: Is this resolved? Then please accept the answer or post a follow up/clarification question in the comments bellow.

Answer (score 2):

Target: get text in a `span` and `href` attribute of a sibling `a` element, if the `span` contains a specified search word.

One way is to look for a `a` having the `href` attribute set, that has a [preceding sibling](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) `span` element. Then select the parent element and therein the `span` element to compare the content. For the parsing of a DOM tree, [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is a good option.

**Example Code**

```
String source = "<div class=\"div\"><span>my y favourite text </span><a href=\"http://www.mylink.com\">my link </a></div>" +
        "<div class=\"div\"><span>my y favourite 2 text </span><a href=\"/some-link.html\">my link 1</a></div>" +
        "<div class=\"div\"><span>my y text </span><a href=\"http://www.mylink.com\">my link 2</a></div>";

String searchWord = "favourite";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source, "UTF-8");
doc.setBaseUri("http://some-source.com"); // only for absolute links in local example

Element parent;
String spanContent="";
String link = "";

for (Element el : doc.select("span ~ a[href]")) {
    parent = el.parent();
    if(parent.select("span").text().contains(searchWord)){
        spanContent = parent.select("span").first().text();
        link = parent.select("a[href]").first().absUrl("href");

        System.out.println(spanContent + " -> " + link); // do something useful with the matches
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
my y favourite text -> http://www.mylink.com
my y favourite 2 text -> http://some-source.com/some-link.html
```

Comment: In the doc.select the ~ is the same of > ?

Comment: is the same that simbol?

Comment: No, > is for the child, ~ is for the sibling. See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp